# Executing controller function with parameters inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, plupload

I'm writing an Angular directive for the [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) library and am running into problems when trying to execute a controller function inside the directive.

The markup of the directive is this:

```
<button plupload pl-url="/upload" pl-files-model="files" pl-upload-progress="uploadProgress();" id="browse">
    ...
</button>
```

As you can see, I'm defining the controller function to be run on a file progress event as an attribute on the element. At the moment that function exists in my controller as this:

```
$scope.uploadProgress = function() {
    console.log("Calling upload progress controller function");
}
```

Then, inside my directive I'm using the following code to execute that function:

```
// Event handler for upload progress
uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {

    var fn = $parse(attrs.plUploadProgress);
    scope.$apply(function(){
        fn(scope.$parent, {$file: file});
    });

});
```

This successfuly executes the controller function, as I can see `Calling upload progress controller function` being printed into the console, however it doesn't seem to pass over any parameters. I'm trying to send the `file` parameter from the `UploadProgress` event. Changing the function to this just printed `undefined` in the console:

```
$scope.uploadProgress = function(test) {
    console.log(test);
}
```

How can I pass parameters into the function call?

Comment: Why don't you use an isolate scope's `&` to pass the function ?

Comment: Because I don't know what that is, can you provide an example?

Comment: Read about it **[here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)**. I can't really know if or how that feats in your app without seeing more code.

Answer (score 0):

### **Method 1**

Basically the method is based on invoking the reference to stored function. And I guess it is also the part that brings the most confusion.

You can pass the function to your directive in normal way:

```
<my-table ... handle="vm.handle"></my-table>
```

But when it comes to calling the function you need a little trick, first invoke the function and later call it with your argument:

```
<button ... ng-click="handle()(item)" ...>
```

**The working example as a Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/txXCXe

### **Method 2**

Simpy pass your function with `=` in your directive, then:

You can pass the function to your directive in normal way:

```
<my-table ... handle="vm.handle"></my-table>
```

And call it with no extra effort

```
<button ... ng-click="handle(item)" ...>
```

**The working example as a Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/qeLF92